# Add new Data Source from an existing DataSet for local report?

Tags: c#, winforms

When using wizard to add a new Data Source to the project, there are 4 options, one goes for **Database**, one goes for **Service**, one goes for **Object** and the last goes for **Sharepoint**. I'm focusing on **Database** and **Object**, these two options are almost the same in how they get data, both of them use SQL query to fetch data, the difference here is **Database** will get data from a procedure or function stored on the server whereas **Object** will get data from a method which executes some SQL query remotely. Using two of these options will make me re-create/re-execute my SQL statement to get data, which is very unnecessary because I already have a Dataset filled with data (for displaying in DataGridView), so why the hell do I have to re-execute the exact SQL statement I've executed when filling my Dataset?

To help you image the context more easily, I'll post some code here:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("My SQL SELECT query", mySqlConnection);
da.Fill(ds,"myTable");
```

Now I want to add ds as a new DataSource for my local report, using wizard doesn't
 seem able to help, the new DataSource I want here can be created through the exact 
"My SQL SELECT query" above, that means ds is already what I want, however I don't know
 how to make it available for my local report's data source.

I hope you understand my problem here, I don't want to do thing which has already been done.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly... You could use an Object method that returns your datasource from your dataset not using SQL if you have the dataset in memory as a dataset. You can use LINQ or the Select() method of a datatable inside your dataset to filter the data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415.aspx

hope it helps.

Comment: I really don't understand how to implement such a method, because as far as I know the method should be static, that means there won't any call from the hidden this pointer in that method and my dataset should be also static to be placed inside the method's body. I don't want it to be static, if I'm wrong at something here, please lighten me. Thanks!

Comment: I dont think they have to be static, you could return a generic collection using LINQ on your in memory dataset. Here are some walkthroughs links that have some examples for returning lists from business objects.

Comment: Please where are the links referred to by 'here' in your words?

Comment: the 4 walkthrough links 2 for windows or 2 for web. Heres another link for dataset to list... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916922/dataset-to-listtusing-linq